# \node : Undefined control sequence with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.5cm,auto,>=latex',
squarednode/.style={rectangle, draw=black!80, fill=black!100, very thick, minimum size=5mm,text=white}]
    \node [squarednode] (encoder) {$\text{encoder}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

When compiling, here is the error message :

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \text 

l.10     \node [squarednode] (encoder) {$\text
                                              {encoder}$};
```

I do not understand... it works perfectly on another .tex that has the same code (but it's a beamer package slide tex file)

Any idea on why this might not work?

Thanks

Comment: You need to load `amsmath` to have `\text` defined.

Comment: That worked. Thanks! I didn't had to load it on my beamer tex file..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to TeX-SE! This has nothing to do with `tikz`, but the error message just tells you that `\text` is not defined. `\text` comes with `amsmath`. Of course, in your application, `\text` is not necessary, you could just do `\node [squarednode] (encoder) {encoder};`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.5cm,auto,>=latex',
squarednode/.style={rectangle, draw=black!80, fill=black!100, very thick, minimum size=5mm,text=white}]
    \node [squarednode] (encoder) {$\text{encoder}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) I didn't knew `@marmots` are faster than Falcons `:-D`.

Comment: @Raaja If we were slower, the eagles could catch us. So we need to be fast. ;-)

Comment: Fair enough (until next-time).